# Proper typewriter font for math symbols (∀, ∃, →), e.g. in verbatim environment

Tags: fonts, unicode, typewriter

I have a listing to be used in verbatim (acutally `Verbatim`) that uses unicode characters such as ∀, ∃, →, ∨. Using

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2203}{\ensuremath\exists}
```

they do appear in the listing, but obviously in the wrong font.

For → I got the desired result using

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\ifmmode\to\else\textrightarrow\fi}
```

but I do not see how to do it for ∃, ∀ and ∨.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\ifmmode\to\else\textrightarrow\fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2203}{\ensuremath\exists}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Make this → ∃ look nice!
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

I’d like to stick to latex (i.e. not xetex). I would prefer to stick to the default type writer font (Computer Modern Typewriter), but if it only works with a different font (such as DejaVu Sans Mono), then that would be ok as well.

Comment: Related: I have tried to find ∀ in `DejaVu Sans Mono` using the `fonttable` package, but could not find it in either `T1` or `TS1` font encoding. Which encoding is used for such symbols?

Comment: Do you have an example document?

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `cmtex10` font, that has several math symbols and is compatible with `cmtt`. The code below assumes you use the characters either in math mode or in `Verbatim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cmtex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmtex}{m}{n}{
 <-> cmtex10
}{}
\newcommand{\cmtex}[1]{{%
  \usefont{U}{cmtex}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}%
}}

\newcommand{\ttexists}{\cmtex{"15}}
\newcommand{\ttforall}{\cmtex{"14}}
\newcommand{\ttrightarrow}{\cmtex{"19}}
\newcommand{\ttlor}{\cmtex{"1F}}
\newcommand{\ttland}{\cmtex{"04}}

\newunicodechar{∃}{\ifmmode\exists\else\ttexists\fi}
\newunicodechar{∀}{\ifmmode\forall\else\ttforall\fi}
\newunicodechar{→}{\ifmmode\expandafter\rightarrow\else\ttrightarrow\fi}
\newunicodechar{∨}{\ifmmode\lor\else\ttlor\fi}
\newunicodechar{∧}{\ifmmode\land\else\ttland\fi}

\begin{document}

$∃∀→∨∧$

\begin{Verbatim}
∃∀→∨∧
abcde
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the font table, so you can extend the set in the same fashion.

[image]

Comment: Great! Could you also add the precise command to get that font table?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I typed `pdflatex nfssfont` from a terminal window and, at the prompt, `cmtex10`; at the next prompt, `\table\bye`. The reference for `cmtex10` is the TeXbook, table at page 369.

Comment: Alignment can be slightly incorrect. I've found that with the character δ in boxes by using the pmboxdraw package. So I needed `\ifmmode\delta\else\makebox[0pt][l]{\ttdelta} \fi`. Not sure whether there is a better solution.

Comment: @vinc17 I'm not sure at all about the zero width box. Without an example with the `pmboxdraw` package it's difficult to say. Please, ask a new question referencing this one.

Comment: The issue actually comes from the use of `scalefont` from the `scalefnt` package. It seems that `cmtex10` doesn't like it. With `article`, I get a warning, but with `beamer`, the breakage is silent. I can ask a new question later if need be.

Comment: I've just asked a new question [Typewriter font for math symbols (∃, ∀) in scaled verbatim environment for pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401652/58921) concerning my issue involving `\scalefont` from the `scalefnt` package.